# How do I use fonts downloaded from NPM (Fontsource) with Tailwind CSS?

Tags: npm, tailwind-css

I'm working on a Next.js project, and when I download the NPM package from Fontsource (using the Advent Pro font), it downloads to my `node_modules` folder. In it has the font files (ttf, toff, etc.), but also CSS files which define the `@font_face` in order to import it into other files.

NPM package in question: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fontsource/advent-pro

According to Tailwind's documentation, I should extend Tailwind's default theme with the new font (in `tailwind.config.js`). Below is my "attempt" at it:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,tsx,jsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,tsx,jsx}",
  ],
  purge: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,tsx,jsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,tsx,jsx}",
  ],
  darkMode: 'class', // or'media' or 'class'  
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'cream': '#FFDFBD',
        'wood': '#460B0B'
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        'darkModeBG': "linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.05), rgba(255,255,255,0.05)), url('~/public/overpass.gif')",
        'lightModeBG': "url('~/public/station.gif')"
      },
      fontFamily: {
        titillium: ['Titillium-Web', 'sans-serif'],
        adventProHeader: ['Advent Pro', 'sans-serif']
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

But on the site, when I apply `font-adventProHeader` to my `<h1>` tag, it applies the sans-serif font.

I don't want to have to rewrite the `@font_face` code from the `node-modules` folder into my `globals.css` file. Is there a way to go about this?

Comment: Have you imported font with `import "@fontsource/advent-pro"`?

Comment: Where should I put that statement? In the ```globals.css``` file or the tailwind config file?

Comment: Try put into globals.css this line `@import '~@fontsource/advent-pro/index.css';`

Comment: Oh wow that works! So I can change the index.css if I want to use a different weight I'm assuming.

Comment: Nope. You should not touch any file under `node_modules`. You should include desired font types into your main CSS or JS file

Comment: I know the NPM module does include multiple weights for this font, is it possible to have 2 of the same font, in different weights, and specify which to use under the tailwind config file? ```index.css``` is one of many font faces within that folder, so if I wanted to use both ```400.css``` and ```700.css```, would I be able to do so?

Comment: Include both of them. You may include as many files as you need

Answer (score 5):

**root.css**

```
@import '@fontsource/fira-code';

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**tailwind.config.ts**

```
theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                fira: 'fira-code, Times New Roman, serif',
            },
        }
    }
```

you can use in any html tag: font-fira